# Solve Picture Stretching

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am making a project in which I am using a cover picture like Google+.
approx Full on screen but when I upload small size pictures or very large size pictures, it stretches or compress in preview.

simple tag I am using to fit in my box is
`<img src="coverphotos/1291384_4846629064030_1548133592_o.jpg" height="530px" width="1024px" style="border-width: 0px; margin-top:-4px">`

Very very important. I wanted to make a cover picture on my project but i am getting irritated because its stretching, and making picture ugly, how Facebook,Google+ upload a cover picture without stretching?

Preview.
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=479959b

I don't want it to get stretch, while uploading on fb and google its works osm

Comment: Can we see some of the markup? this alone makes it pretty difficult to assess other options besides whats already been provided by others.

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=479959b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your link, this css fixed the issue.

```
body {
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
}

center {
 width:100%;
}

center img {
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: if i put height: auto; den it will overflow and other div will be start behaving madly :P. i just want to not to overflow it and don't stretch..

Comment: In that case, whatever height you want it to be, set center to that explicit height, so center{width:100%; height: 530px; overflow:hidden;} the overflow hidden will prevent the image from going any further, also, you another option is to set the image as the background image of center and set it to background-size: cover, that will be the best way to acheive the effect your looking for

Comment: yeah thanks you are awesome. and can you also give some tutorial or link to change background position please.

Comment: This was posted above: its a good tutorial on how to do full screen background images. Also, if my solution solved your problem, please vote it as the correct answer. Not sure what you mean by "cane background position". http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: sorry it was "change".. i dont want to make it on full screen,

Comment: depends on how you want to change it. if your talking specifically about the width, you can keep the width at 100% and change the wrapper (center) to whatever width youd like and it will resize itself to fit that width. and should stay proportionate if you have overflow hidden on.

Comment: i get your point buy my question is how to reposition the image (like fb)dynamically ,after uploading, so that i can set the favorite part of my pic..?

Comment: gotcha, you want to select a certain portion of the image to show during or after the upload, thats a much more complicated issue, involving some serious javascript i'm sure, maybe work on it yourself for awhile and post some questions back here when you hit a wall.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the `height` to `530px` OR set the `width` to `100%`, don't do both together.

The picture will not be stretched and will maintain its aspect ratio. :)

Comment: i cant set its height auto :(

Answer (score 1):

This: `height="530px" width="100%"`

You're telling the picture to take the full width of its parent and to be exactly 530px high. What you probably want is unconstrained height on the image, but constrained height on its parent with `overflow: hidden`.

Take a look at this article: [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: what its solution then?

Comment: i cant set its height auto :(